# Nuget Package Manager not working in VS Express 2013

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013.

When trying to install a nuget package, I am getting an error (no error when trying in 2012 express):

```
PM> Install-Package AutoMapper
Install-Package : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  AutoMapper
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Internet is working (I have Vs 2012 working and installing nuget packages at the same time - with no issues).

VS -> Tools -> Extensions and Updates says: `Cannot check for updates because the following error(s) occurred whil trying to contact the server: Unable to connect to the remote server - please click here to retry the request` - when I click that, it goes back to the "retrieving information" loop.

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?

Thank you, Mark

Comment: Have you tried the GUI version of Nuget in VS?

Comment: Hi - yes - it just says "retrieving information" endlessly - thank you, Mark

Comment: Is your internet connection working?

Comment: Can you check if your NuGet installation is up to date? Within VS: *Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates*

Comment: Yes internet is working - Tools -> Extensions and Updates says: Cannot check for updates because the following error(s) occurred whil trying to contact the server: Unable to connect to the remote server - please click here to retry the request - when I click that, it goes back to the "retrieving information" loop.  Thank you, Mark

Comment: Sounds like a firewall or a misconfigured proxy is blocking internet access for your VS 2013 installation.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  I was able to connect to NuGet from VS2013 if I select "Run As Administrator" when launching VS.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and it was solved by disabling the firewall.
Later I enabled the firewall and checked the blocked programs and unblocked visual studio, which for some reason had been blocked.