# Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 - Tools and Extensions Not reaching the internet

Tags: visual-studio-2013, updates

I've just updated Visual Studio 2013 with Update 4, and my tools and extensions manager isn't able to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I thought I would post my solution to this annoying problem.
My proxy settings for access behind my company's firewall had been removed with the update.

Go here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE
find this file
devenv.exe.config

edit system.net to include this:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
    <proxy proxyaddress="http://yourproxy:8080" />
</defaultProxy>
<settings>
    <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    <ipv6 enabled="true" />
</settings>
</system.net>
```

Note that you'll need to edit this in a text program that you run with admin permissions.